# how to get attending response of calendar event

Tags: java, calendar

i am making an app with which i fill details of creating an event like(event id ,start time,end time ,description etc.) and send these details via message to another person who also has my app.

When another person receives my message ,BroadcastReciever gets on and displays event notification to that person.
He may select attending-yes ,no or maybe.
My problem is that i want to get that attending status.
I don't know how to get that status.
Please help

Comment: i am using java language

Comment: Could you not include the address to send responses to, as part of your broadcast message?